# Responsive on IPAD

Tags: ipad, responsive-design

I have used media queries for the responsive css for the following site:
www.landscontracting.co.uk

The site looks ok on a 3rd generation ipad however the responsive is not being brought in at all for portrait on a 1st generation ipad.

I have the following line in the index.php:
 
If i remove this then the first generation ipad looks fine presumably as its just adjusting the zoom on the desktop version of the site however all other phones and 3rd gen ipad no longer has the correct styling.

How can i get the 1st generation ipad to call in the css i have used for the 3rd generation ipad which is a combination of @media (max-width: 980px) and @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
/* target iPads (portrait)  */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Source: http://is.gd/FiMOPn

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I found it at a random px width and inserted a min and max difference of about 2 px. Not a great solution but job done i guess